# How can you add EC2 instance attributes at launch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

We're using Amazon ECS for our services. We have a cluster called `application` and within that cluster, we have several services:

```
- dev_app
- dev_kafka
- dev_zookeeper
- qa_app
- qa_kafka
- qa_zookeeper
- etc.
```

And the services pull from task definitions that have correlating constraints, i.e., `memberOf(attribute:env == qa), memberOf(attribute:role == zookeeper)`

We launch our instances via EC2 launch configurations + Autoscaling Groups. This means that our services can't actually auto-scale right now, because instances launch without the appropriate attributes. The only way I know how to add the attributes currently is to wait for the instance to be added to the `application` cluster, and go in to manually add custom attributes to each instance.

**The question**: Can I somehow add instance attributes via the launch configuration, or some other means, at launch?

I've found [`modify-instance-attribute`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/modify-instance-attribute.html), but this only seems to be valid for existing attributes, not custom attributes. I've also tried [`put-attributes`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/put-attributes.html), but this seems to only be valid for ECS resources (my instance ARN is apparently invalid).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use "user data" in launch configuration.

```
echo ECS_INSTANCE_ATTRIBUTES={\"mycostomattr\":\"myvalue\"} >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-config.html

Comment: This is what we ended up doing, and I completely forgot to come back and post it as an answer. So, points for you!

Comment: Do you know how to add multiple attributes in launch configuration? I use `echo ECS_INSTANCE_ATTRIBUTES={\"mycostomattr\":\"myvalue\",\"mycostomattr2\":\"myvalue2\"} >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config` but it seems like failed.

Comment: @suanziliu did you find the solution for multiple attributes

Comment: @kumar yes, I used cloudformation template, and the structure looks like this.
```
  APUserData:
    Type: String
    Default: |
      #! /bin/bash
      echo 'ECS_INSTANCE_ATTRIBUTES={"ap":"member","consul":"member"}' >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config;
...
  APServerLaunchConfig:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Properties:
      LaunchConfigurationName: example
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          !Ref APUserData
```

Comment: got from aws support echo ECS_INSTANCE_ATTRIBUTES='{"key1":"test","key2":"test2"}' >>  /etc/ecs/ecs.config

Answer (score 1):

If we are using single agent configuration variable like cluster name, then we use below syntax in user data.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "ECS_CLUSTER=MyCluster" >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

But if we have multiple  variable to write to /etc/ecs/ecs.config use the below format.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat <<'EOF' >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
ECS_CLUSTER=MyCluster
ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_TYPE=docker
ECS_LOGLEVEL=debug
EOF
```

In cloudformation, instance user-data we have to apply

```
"#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
"cat <<'EOF' >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config \n",
"ECS_CLUSTER=", { "Ref": "MyCluster" },
"\n",
"ECS_LOGLEVEL=debug\n",
"ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_TYPE=docker\n",
"EOF"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to pass values and perform specific functions of installing packages on to your instance at the launch then you can do so via the user data.When you define the auto scaling configuration you can specify your input on the third step which has user data text input box.

For example, the below bash script is input as user data and installs the web server on the instance.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 yum update -y
 yum install -y httpd24 php56 mysql55-server php56-mysqlnd
 service httpd start
 chkconfig httpd on
 groupadd www
 usermod -a -G www ec2-user
 chown -R root:www /var/www
 chmod 2775 /var/www
 find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} +
 find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} +
 echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > /var/www/html/phpinfo.php
```

Comment: Yeah I know this much unfortunately, but the question is *what* do I actually put in the user data to get it to apply custom attributes to itself?

Comment: Ok got that .Have you tried using describe-instance-attribute http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstanceAttribute.html

Comment: `describe-*` api calls only give details, they don't usually allow you to set anything new

Comment: Sorry MrDuk I got it now.You would need a DevOps tool like Ansible to do it for you.