# How to add a custom attribute in cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want to add a custom attribute to an ec2 instance created in cloudformation, such that it'll show up in the output of `aws ecs describe-container-instances ...` as an ATTRIBUTE. I can't find anywhere in any documentation that describes how to do it. I've tried metadata, and that didn't work. There's gotta be a way!

Comment: Did you see this answer?  It deals with ECS, but might work:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45956888/819019

Comment: @Taterhead That totally does work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar question was asked related to adding attributes "at launch".

Try the following:

```
echo ECS_INSTANCE_ATTRIBUTES={\"mycostomattr\":\"myvalue\"} >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

reference AWS doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-config.html

and SO question: [How can you add EC2 instance attributes at launch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44790491/how-can-you-add-ec2-instance-attributes-at-launch)